# Da para saber o tempo de resposta de uma requisição AJAX com jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Queria saber se existe alguma função que retorne o tempo de requisição AJAX em microssegundos, pois eu preciso obter esse valor para o projeto que estou desenvolvendo.

Comment: Você precisa fazer isso via código? Porque as ferramentas de desenvolvedor dos browsers mostram o tempo.

Comment: Isso mesmo, eu irei utilizar pelo código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa guardar um timestamp do momento da requisição, obter outro no momento da resposta, e comparar os dois:

```js
var inicio = performance.now();
$.get('https://httpbin.org/get').done( function(response) {
    var tempo = performance.now() - inicio;
    console.log('A requisição levou ' + tempo + 'ms');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

O tempo está em milissegundos, mas repare que tem casas decimais. Isso só é possível com `performance.now()`, sem suporte em browsers antigos, em vez de `Date.getTime()`, que não tem problemas de suporte.